# Save multiple images paths to realtime database firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am uploading 6 images to firebase storage and save images paths and some data  in firebase database. So far it works when only all 6 images are upload.

I am BSimagePicker library https://github.com/siralam/BSImagePicker to select multiple images then upload them to storage and save paths in database.

The issue I am having is, if I want to upload less than 6 images then it crashes and points me to the PUTFILE that is null. 
How do I make a condition that if a uri is null then it's ok to upload?

Also, what would be the best approach of the way I handled the path upload?

I can't find a tutorial regarding uploading multiple files and save their paths to realtime database. All there is a single file.

```
private void startPosting() {

    mPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(ImageLoader.TAG, "onClick: attempting to post...");
            if (!isEmpty(mTitle.getText().toString())
                    && !isEmpty(mDescription.getText().toString())
                    && !isEmpty(mPrice.getText().toString())
                    && !isEmpty(mCountry.getText().toString())
                    && !isEmpty(mStateProvince.getText().toString())
                    && !isEmpty(mCity.getText().toString())
                    && !isEmpty(mContactEmail.getText().toString())) {

                if (mAllUri != null ) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    final String postId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();

                    StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                                    "/" + postId + "/post_image");

                    final StorageReference filepath1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                                    "/" + postId + "/post_image1");
                    final StorageReference filepath2 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                                    "/" + postId + "/post_image2");
                    final StorageReference filepath3 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                                    "/" + postId + "/post_image3");
                    final StorageReference filepath4 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                                    "/" + postId + "/post_image4");
                    final StorageReference filepath5 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                                    "/" + postId + "/post_image5");

                    final Uri[] firebaseUri = new Uri[1];
                    final Uri[] firebaseUri1 = new Uri[1];
                    final Uri[] firebaseUri2 = new Uri[1];
                    final Uri[] firebaseUri3 = new Uri[1];
                    final Uri[] firebaseUri4 = new Uri[1];
                    final Uri[] firebaseUri5 = new Uri[1];


                    filepath.putFile(mSelectedUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            firebaseUri[0] = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    filepath1.putFile(mSelectedUri1).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                             firebaseUri1[0] = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    filepath2.putFile(mSelectedUri2).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                             firebaseUri2[0] = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    filepath3.putFile(mSelectedUri3).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                             firebaseUri3[0] = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    filepath4.putFile(mSelectedUri4).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                         public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                             firebaseUri4[0] = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    filepath5.putFile(mSelectedUri5).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                            firebaseUri5[0] = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                            Post post = new Post();
                            post.setCity(mCity.getText().toString());
                            post.setContact_email(mContactEmail.getText().toString());
                            post.setCountry(mCountry.getText().toString());
                            post.setDescription(mDescription.getText().toString());
                            post.setPost_id(postId);
                            post.setPrice(mPrice.getText().toString());
                            post.setState_province(mStateProvince.getText().toString());
                            post.setTitle(mTitle.getText().toString());
                            post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                            post.setImage(firebaseUri[0].toString());
                            post.setImage1(firebaseUri1[0].toString());
                            post.setImage2(firebaseUri2[0].toString());
                            post.setImage3(firebaseUri3[0].toString());
                            post.setImage4(firebaseUri4[0].toString());
                            post.setImage5(firebaseUri5[0].toString());


                            reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                                    .child(postId)
                                    .setValue(post);
                            showProgressBar();
                            resetFields();

                        }

                    });
                        }//file4
                    });//file4
                        } //file3
                    }); //file3
                        }//file2
                    }); //file2
                        }//file1
                    });//file1
                        }
                    });
                }

           //
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Here is the function that retrieves uri:

```
@Override
public void onMultiImageSelected(List<Uri> uriList, String tag) {
    for (int i = 0; i < uriList.size(); i++) {
        mAllUri = uriList.get(i);
        if (i >= 6) return;
        ImageView iv;
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                iv = ivImage1;
                mSelectedUri = uriList.get(0);
                Log.d(ImageLoader.TAG, "aissa image" + mSelectedUri);

                break;
            case 1:
                iv = ivImage2;
                mSelectedUri1 = uriList.get(1);
                Log.d(ImageLoader.TAG, "aissa1 image" + mSelectedUri1);
                break;
            case 2:
                iv = ivImage3;
                mSelectedUri2 = uriList.get(2);
                break;
            case 3:
                iv = ivImage4;
                mSelectedUri3 = uriList.get(3);
                break;
            case 4:
                iv = ivImage5;
                mSelectedUri4 = uriList.get(4);
                break;
            case 5:
            default:
                iv = ivImage6;
                mSelectedUri5 = uriList.get(5);
        }
        Glide.with(this).load(uriList.get(i)).into(iv);

    }
}
```

Complete class:
https://pastebin.com/BR6M8jC2

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you want to have a way that does not puts null in your ImageView.

For that you can just check, if the item you're retrieving from the ArrayList is null or not, in other words, just put an `if` statement before putting them in your `mSelectedURi` variables.

So, the last code you've put should look something like this:

```java
@Override
public void onMultiImageSelected(List<Uri> uriList, String tag) {
    for (int i = 0; i < uriList.size(); i++) {
        mAllUri = uriList.get(i);
        if (i >= 6) return;
        ImageView iv;
        switch (i) {

            case 1:
                iv = ivImage2;
                if(uriList.get(1)!=null && !uriList.get(1).equals("")){
                     mSelectedUri1 = uriList.get(1);
                     Log.d(ImageLoader.TAG, "aissa1 image" + mSelectedUri1);
                }
                else
                  // do something when it is null, like displaying a toast or something

                break;

            case 2:
            // do this for all these cases
    }

}
```

Comment: Then you should be using it without checking if it is null, somewhere else too, see where the logcat points you at, and put the same conditions like here in that place too.

Comment: The logcat points at :                         filepath3.putFile(mSelectedUri3).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
 when I select 3 pictures. The thing is how do I condition it the way my code is written?  I can't find a better way, like using an array or something

Comment: You can just put the null checking if condition above all these places and put the code inside it.

Comment: I have tried that already. But if it's null then the code inside won't execute

Comment: And that's what you want, right? If it's null why would you want to save it anyways, if its not null, you can do what you want with it.

Comment: The code inside is user's info. I need that to be uploaded.

Comment: Only place the code that can be null inside that `if` statement all other that is not null can go outside the `if` statement. We are using `if` to avoid null to be uploaded, because that field does not have the valid data. The fields which have valid data need not to be put inside that `if`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use the if statement in this situation. addOnSuccessListener are all nested together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184545/discussion-between-pradyumandixit-and-sifaks-agizul).